# What options are there for generating certificate sign request, signing it and verifying it?

Tags: java, security, certificate, bouncycastle, csr

In my java application, I want to have blow functionalities:

• Generate a `Certificate Sign Request (CSR)`, send it over to the other party which is my own Certificate Authority (CA).

• Have my CA `sign this Certificate Request` and send it back.

• Have users `verify each others' certificate` to be signed by the CA.

What libraries can I use?
I searched a little and found BouncyCastle.

Do I have any more options and if yes, please say how you compare them.

Comment: BouncyCastle is de facto Java cryptography standard and can do all of these and you would need some communication protocol library for interaction with CA.

Comment: OK. I have been looking for examples, the difficulty comes when you try to put these examples together.
I would really benefit it if somebody publishes a sample simple java project that does both generating a Certificate Request, and then signs it.
My confusion comes partially from the fact that API has got some updates and that makes these examples not work perfectly when you put them together.
For the moment its a bit tough for me to get things working.

Comment: You can find a lot of code samples even on stackoverflow alone.

Answer (score 0):

EMC^2 (formerly RSA) has a Java library called BSafe that is a commercial product that you can buy that has just about every kind of PKI / Cryptography libraries and APIs that you could use, complete with sample code.

Here is the link: http://www.emc.com/security/rsa-bsafe.htm

There is also an open-source free one called RSA Share for Java (or JSafe), that RSA makes.  Of course it is a very stripped-down version of BSafe (their commercial product)

https://community.emc.com/community/edn/rsashare